# CORS | Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers ionic | IOS 13 preflight response

Tags: ionic-framework, cors, wkwebview, ios13, ionic-v1

I have migrate my IOS ionic v1 app to IOS 13 and xcode 11.5. when I install the app and try to login first time then I am able to login successfully. But when I kill the app and try to open the app then it wont allow me to auto login. My service in deployed into **IIS**.

In the config.xml have added these settings

```
<preference name="WKSuspendInBackground" value="false" />
<preference name="iosScheme" value="httpsionic" />
<allow-navigation href="httpsionic://*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8100/*" />
```

when i try to open the app after killing the app from task manager. it wont allow me to login. Its giving me an error

> Request header field Authorization is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

First Time run when I install the app work as expected :-

[image]

after killing the app and open it again :-
[image]

this is the console log
[image]

Please let me know what I am missing something here so that access the app without this above CORS error.
this is my **ionic info**

```
Ionic:
   Ionic CLI         : 5.3.0
   Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.2.4
   @ionic/v1-toolkit : 2.0.11

Cordova:
   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 18 other plugins)

Utility:
   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.8 (update available: 1.0.0)

System:
   ios-deploy : 1.9.0
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v10.16.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.9.0
   OS         : macOS Catalina
   Xcode      : Xcode 11.5 Build version 11E608c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did not get any solution for IIS

It might be helpful for someone how is facing this issue. So I have migrated my service to azure web apps. and all CORS issues are resolved using below command. In azure I am able to add Custom Origins after running these command from terminal.

To do this:

> 1. Open Terminal in your Mac
> 2. Run: /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
> 3. Once that is finished: brew update && brew install azure-cli
> 4. Then login with your credentials by running: az login.  this will ask you to open a website to authorize your device
>    https://aka.ms/devicelogin
> 5. Then run the azure CLI command for your specific app (this is an example of my app): az webapp cors add --allowed-origins
>    ionic://***.com --name *** --resource-group ***

**References:**

HOWTO install Azure CLI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-macos?view=azure-cli-latest
Configure CORS with Azure CLI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/cors?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-cors-add

Note :- Most welcome, if someone found the solution of IIS please post here add link for reference.